# Remove Crouton's messages transparency

Tags: android, crouton

I have problem with crouton transparency in my program. At this moment when crouton is displayed  in layout with for example button the button is visible on croutons message. I would like crouton message to be fully opaque. https://github.com/keyboardsurfer/Crouton

Screen:

[image]

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're using one the default `Style`s of `Crouton`, you should not have any transparency.

If you have set the color with the `Style.Builder.setBackgroundColorValue(...)` make sure that your color does not have transparency.

If you're experiencing this with a default `Style` feel free to [open an issue](https://github.com/keyboardsurfer/Crouton/issues/new).